# Java Eclipse - Goto URL Method?

Tags: java, eclipse, url

I have a question, that I have been trying to solve for days now.
I am using Eclipse to create a Java Application along with the Window Builder.
My question is, I have a button on the main frame, and if someone clicks on that button, a browser should be opened, and the given URL should be opened.

Is such method possible in Java?
I have tried various things but I just can't figure it out.

Comment: the URL can be opened in the Java browser (part of Java), not in the actual browser (IE, Firefox, etc)

Comment: Wht do you mean by the Java Browser? Will the user be able to view a normal static website with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Desktop.browse(URI)`.
More info here:

- [http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120627043647/http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/javase6/desktop_api/)
- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29

Comment: @PitaSivam: follow the links `Martin` included in his answer.Try googling and than come to us with some specific problem.

Comment: I imported java.awt.Desktop then

for a button click I coded the method

public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
Desktop.browse();
}

I don't know what to put inside the brackets, i tried the url but it says that string is not allowed. what can i do?

Comment: It says cannot make a static reference to the non static method browse(URI) from the type desktop

Comment: Just to make clear, I haven't created a separate class or such for Desktop?

I have got a class called Form and that is my main interface with buttons etc etc. One of the buttons is called Web-Admin. and when that button is clicked, the specific url shall be called.

All i have done here is, i imported the Desktop package in the Form class then when i created the button, i added a mouse click event and wrote the code Desktop.browse(new URI("http://google.com"));

Comment: @Pita: Use `Desktop.getDesktop()` to acquire a Desktop object.

Comment: you mean i should rather write Desktop.getDesktop("URL");

Comment: its not doing anything, when i do that

Comment: `desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();` and than `desktop.browse(new URI("google.com"));`

Comment: Also check this condition `if (Desktop.isDesktopSupported())`

Comment: I tried it. Still doesn't work unfortunately :( It says, desktop cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: What I earlier meant was this `Desktop desktop = null;` and than `desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();`.

Comment: where do i specify the url then?

Comment: `Desktop desktop = null;` and than `desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();` and than `desktop.browse(new URI("google.com"));`. Now tell me is the error `desktop cannot be resolved to a variable` gone.

Comment: it says now unhanded exception type IOException

Comment: are you using any IDE.? If not just add `IOException` to the class or method in which the above code resides like for eg: `public void open_url(URI uri) throws IOException` or `public myclass throws IOException` or `public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException`.

Comment: well i am just writing java using eclipse and also the window builder.

Comment: doesn't eclipse automatically add try-catch block to handle exceptions thrown. I know netbeans does.

Comment: If the above code is inside this `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0)`  method just do `public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) throws IOException`.

Comment: woow, it actually works now. it automatically added the try and catch block to handle exceptions :) Many Thanks. you have been really helpful ran rag :)

Answer (score 3):

Use [Desktop.browse(URI)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#browse%28java.net.URI%29).

Comment: how do i use it ? could you please explain? I have already tried that